# trying to get the average of difference between Start and End time

Tags: sql

I have formatted the 2 time columns, by using the below query, however in order to get the average I am unable to convert it to Integer.

example : 11:00 AM - 12:15 PM = 01:15 (got it from my query)
**01:15*24*60 = 75** (unable to get this conversion)

> SQL Error : conversion failed when converting varchar value to data type integer.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong or is there a better way to get the average of difference in time ?

Query:

```
   SELECT
   CONVERT(varchar(5),
   DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, check_in_time, PHYS_SEEN_TIME), 0), 114) AS 'WAITING TIME',HealthCenter_APPT, cast('WAITING TIME' AS int)
   from [HIM_Clinical].[dbo].[APPOINTMENT_DATA] (NOLOCK)
   where CHECK_IN_TIME is not null
   and PHYS_SEEN_TIME is not null
   AND APPOINTMENT_DATE>= '01-Jan-2020' and APPOINTMENT_DATE<= '30-Sep-2020' 
   AND [Appointment_Status] IN ('Checked In','Checked Out','No Show')
```

Comment: cast('WAITING TIME' AS int) , this is totally wrong , you are trying to convert 'Waiting Time' string to int not the column and doesn't this `DATEDIFF(minute, check_in_time, PHYS_SEEN_TIME)` already gives you the time difference in minute ( int) ??

Comment: yes, DATEDIFF(minute, check_in_time, PHYS_SEEN_TIME) this is giving me the time difference but i am unable to apply Avg to this by Healthcenter appt

Comment: @nidhi . . . Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the avg per `HealthCenter_APPT`, so you have to `GROUP BY` that column:

```
SELECT 
    HealthCenter_APPT
   , AVG(DATEDIFF(minute, check_in_time, PHYS_SEEN_TIME)) AS 'WAITING TIME'
    
FROM 
   [HIM_Clinical].[dbo].[APPOINTMENT_DATA](NOLOCK)
WHERE 
   CHECK_IN_TIME IS NOT NULL
    AND PHYS_SEEN_TIME IS NOT NULL
    AND APPOINTMENT_DATE >= '01-Jan-2020'
    AND APPOINTMENT_DATE <= '30-Sep-2020'
    AND [Appointment_Status] IN (
        'Checked In'
        ,'Checked Out'
        ,'No Show'
        )
GROUP BY
  HealthCenter_APPT
```